# uncovering the math statements in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations

I am trying to divide one mathematical statement, which has been written in `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, into several parts, so that each part is shown in a new page together with previous parts. The statement is:

```
\documentclass[openany]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix{
    \cdots\ar[r]& B\ar[rr]^{h}\ar@{.>}[dr] & & A\ar[rr]^{g}\ar@{.>}[dr] & & F\ar[r]^{f} & D\ar[r] & 0\\
    & & C\ar@{.>}[ur]\ar@{.>}[dr] & &E\ar@{.>}[ur]\ar@{.>}[dr]\\
    & 0\ar@{.>}[ur]& &0\ar@{.>}[ur] & & 0 \\
  }
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to first show one part from right hand side and its related arrows, then the middle part together with the first part, and at the end the whole statement.
Since I can not break `\begin{equation} ...\end{equation}`, I could not use `\uncover`.

I would appreciate if one could please help me.

later:
@daleif,
My written codes, following your codes:
(It needs some reformation)

```
\documentclass[openany]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \pause
        \only<1->{
        bla bla bla}

\pause
\only<2->{      
                \begin{equation*}
            \xymatrix{
                \only<10->{\cdots\ar[r]}
                &
                \only<-8>{\phantom{B}}
                \only<8->{B}
                \only<9->{\ar[rr]^{h}}
                \only<8->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
                &
                &
                \only<-5>{\phantom{A}}
                \only<5->{A}
                \only<6->{\ar[rr]^{g}}
                \only<5->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
                &
                &
                \only<-3>{\phantom{F}}
                \only<3->{F}
                \only<3->{\ar[r]^{f}}
                &
                \only<-3>{\phantom{D}}
                \only<3->{D}
                \only<3->{\ar[r]}
                &
                \only<3>{\phantom{0}}
                \only<3->{0}
                \\
                &
                &
                \only<-7>{\phantom{C}}
                \only<7->{C \ar@{.>}[ur]}
                \only<8->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
                &
                &
                \only<-4>{\phantom{E)}}
                \only<4->{E\ar@{.>}[ur]}
                \only<5->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
                \\
                &
                \only<-7>{\phantom{0}}
                \only<7->{0\ar@{.>}[ur]}
                &
                &
                \only<-4>{\phantom{0}}
                \only<4->{0\ar@{.>}[ur]}
                &
                &
                \only<5->{0}
                \\
            }
            \end{equation*}
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which package defines the `\xymatrix` macro? It would be helpful if you expanded your code into a compilable program.

Comment: You can use `\only<>` instead of `\uncover`.

Comment: Dear Mico, I added the full code. I tried \only. But actually I do not know how to use these commands in equations.

Comment: @Mico, if you try `\only<2->{B\ar[rr]^{h}\ar@{.>}[dr]}` then the diagram wobbles. But this works `\only<1>{\phantom{B}}\only<2->{B\ar[rr]^{h}\ar@{.>}[dr]}`

Comment: You make an error in the `<...>` the intervals must not overlap, thus `<-3>` followed (in the same cell) by `<3->` creates problems as both items draw something at step 3.

Comment: See my update....

Answer (score 3):

Fiddly, but it can be done

```
\documentclass[openany]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix{
    \cdots\ar[r]
    &
    B\vphantom{\smash[b]{\dfrac{1}{2}}}
    \only<2->{\ar[rr]^{h}}
    \only<6->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
    &
    &
    \only<1>{\phantom{A}}
    \only<2->{A}
    \only<3->{\ar[rr]^{g}}
    \only<7->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
    &
    &
    \only<-2>{\phantom{F}}
    \only<3->{F}
    \only<4->{\ar[r]^{f}}
    &
    \only<-3>{\phantom{D}}
    \only<4->{D}
    \only<5->{\ar[r]}
    &
    \only<-4>{\phantom{0}}
    \only<5->{0}
    \\
    &
    &
    \only<-5>{\phantom{C}}
    \only<6->{C \ar@{.>}[ur]}
    \only<8->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
    &
    &
    \only<-6>{\phantom{E}}
    \only<7->{E\ar@{.>}[ur]}
    \only<8->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
    \\
    &
    \only<-7>{\phantom{0}}
    \only<8->{0\ar@{.>}[ur]}
    &
    &
    \only<-7>{\phantom{0}}
    \only<8->{0\ar@{.>}[ur]}
    &
    &
    \only<8->{0}
    \\
  }
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: Here is a slight cleanup of the OPs furhter attempts. 
One very specific thing to note in a cell a construction with `\only<-a>{\phantom{...}}` followed by `\only<b->{....}` the `-a` and `b-` intervals must not overlap. If we use say `-3` and `3-` then *both* `\only` contributes to overlay 3 giving an unwanted wobble.

Please update the overlay specifications to your own specifications.

```
\documentclass[openany]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \pause
        \only<1->{
        bla bla bla}

\pause
\only<2->{      
  \begin{equation*}
    \xymatrix{
      \only<-9>{\phantom{{}\cdots{}}}
      \only<10->{\cdots}
      \only<11->{\ar[r]}
      &
      \only<-7>{\phantom{B}}
      \vphantom{\smash[b]{\dfrac{1}{2}}}
      \only<8->{B}
      \only<9->{\ar[rr]^{h}}
      \only<8->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
      &
      &
      \only<-5>{\phantom{A}}
      \only<6->{A}
      \only<6->{\ar[rr]^{g}}
      \only<5->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
      &
      &
      \only<-2>{\phantom{F}}
      \only<3->{F}
      \only<3->{\ar[r]^{f}}
      &
      \only<-2>{\phantom{D}}
      \only<3->{D}
      \only<3->{\ar[r]}
      &
      \only<-2>{\phantom{0}}
      \only<3->{0}
      \\
      &
      &
      \only<-7>{\phantom{C}}
      \only<8->{C\ar@{.>}[ur]}
      \only<8->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
      &
      &
      \only<-4>{\phantom{E}}
      \only<5->{E\ar@{.>}[ur]}
      \only<5->{\ar@{.>}[dr]}
      \\
      &
      \only<-7>{\phantom{0}}
      \only<8->{0\ar@{.>}[ur]}
      &
      &
      \only<-3>{\phantom{0}}
      \only<4->{0\ar@{.>}[ur]}
      &
      &
      \only<-4>{\phantom{0}}
      \only<5->{0}
      \\
    }
  \end{equation*}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice job. The oreder that I want is from right to left. I tried to make changes in your written commands. It worked but not so nicely. The orders of appearing are as I want but sometimes the statement goes out of the page. I put the codes below.

Comment: I put the codes in my question comment. I will be thankful if you could please take a look at it to see why it deas not work well as yours.